# Change footer toolbar width in extjs 5 form

Tags: extjs

I've created a simple form using extjs 5 which has an footer bar.
I want to set the toolbar to a specific width, while the form itself should take 100% width of the parent container.

Here's a jsfiddle with a sample form: [sampleform](http://jsfiddle.net/flow82/hWGYE/4317/)

I've played around for a while but don't get a solution...
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Code of the form:

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title : 'Test',
        renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
        defaultType : 'textfield',
        fieldDefaults : {
            labelAlign : 'left',
            labelWidth : 175,
        },
        items : [{
                fieldLabel : 'Field 1'
            }, {
                fieldLabel : 'Field 2'
            }, {
                fieldLabel : 'Field 3'
            }
        ],
        // Reset and Submit buttons
        fbar : {
            layout : {
                width : 300,
                type : 'fit'
            },
            items : [{
                    text : 'Reset'
                }
            ],
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `maxWidth` on the fbar:

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.form.*']);

Ext.onReady(function () {

    var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title: 'Test',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        fieldDefaults: {
            labelAlign: 'left',
            labelWidth: 175,
        },
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'Field 1'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Field 2'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Field 3'
        }],
        // Reset and Submit buttons
        fbar: {
            maxWidth: 300,
            items: [{
                text: 'Reset'
            }],
        }
    })
});
```